# Prevent CSS transform elements from going off screen

Tags: jquery, css

I have two columns of boxes, and I'm using jQuery to add the following class on hover:

```
.transition {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2); 
    -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
    -o-transform: scale(1.2);
    transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

The HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="expand">
    content...
</div>
```

And the jQuery like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.expand').hover(function() {
        $(this).addClass('transition');
    }, function() {
        $(this).removeClass('transition');
    });
});
```

The problem is that when the box scales, part of it gets cut off because it goes off the screen (boxes in the left column get cut off on the left, boxes in the right column on the right). What I need is for the box to scale AND shift slightly toward the center of the screen. I've been messing around with changing the `margin` property on hover, but when a box shifts it pushes the box next to it on to the next row.

So basically I need the element to scale, slightly shift toward the center so the box doesn't get cut off, and come OUT from the screen (Z-index?) so that it doesn't displace neighboring boxes.

Is this possible? Maybe I should try a different approach like using a jQuery plugin instead of just using jQuery to append a CSS class?

Comment: please include your relevant HTML

Comment: OK, I just did. Thanks.

Comment: You can use the transform: translate(X,Y) to change the rendering position of the element.

Comment: you can also set the origin of the transformation using `transform-origin`, to allow the right column elements to scale only to the left and the left column elements only to grow to the right (same you can set for the vertical axis) [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/n8oda6n1/) ... also ... IMHO just for hover js is a bit overkill, don't you think?

Comment: That works, but I want the boxes on the left to shift right and the boxes on the right to shift left. Maybe the best way to accomplish this is to have a `.transition-left` and `.transition-right` class and figure out how to dynamically apply each class based on whether the box is on the right or left...

Comment: @MartinTurjak - `transform-origin` might be what I need. Seeing if I can make this work now. Thanks!

Comment: also ... if you have 2 columns, you can use `:nth-child(2n)` in the css to apply style just to every second element. [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/n8oda6n1/1/) ... again ... no js needed ;-)

Comment: Martin, you should have added that as answer, it's the obvious correct answer

Comment: Yes, if you add it as an answer I'll "checkmark it"; not sure if that adds to your street cred or what, but that did fix the problem. Thanks!

And I'll try using nth-child as well. The js I wrote to apply the appropriate class to every other element is working fine, but it's probably better to do it all in css if I can.

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understand, you want to scale an element. But when you did it, part of this back is out of the view/window/body...

So, you need to do that with JavaScript...
Use JavaScript to get the current scale of the element, get the element width, multiply width by scale.

Now, you know the scaled width and you can deal with it.

If you want a better answer, give us more info about how you want the element to become.